# Evaluate as many parameters as possible (SymPy)

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation, sympy, evaluation, evalf

I have this code in SymPy:

```
from sympy import *
par_amplitude, par_const_force = symbols('Delta_U f')
equation = par_amplitude * par_const_force
print(equation.evalf(subs={'f':3, 'Delta_U':2}))
```

The output is obviously `6`.

My problem occurs when I have access to only one parameter, like so:

```
print(equation.evalf(subs={'Delta_U':2}))
```

Instead of expected `2 * f` I get `Delta_U * f`.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to evaluate an expression, where not all parameters are available?

EDIT:

Yes, I am after a mixed numerical/symbolic output. Imagine a situation where there is a lot of parameters (generated automatically, so you're not even sure how many), and there is a function supplying all the `subs` values. If you were to miss just one substitution value, you get basically nothing out of `evalf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute in your symbolic expression before evaluating numerically:

```
print(equa.subs({'Delta_U':2}))
print(equa.subs({'Delta_U':2}).evalf())
```

Substitution also yields `6` even without numerical evaluation:

```
print(equa.subs({'Delta_U':2, 'f':3}))
```

**EDIT**: I have an idea why `evalf(...)` will not return `2*f`. I assume that `evalf` tries to only return completely numerical result, but `2*f` is clearly something mixed. A numerical `2` and a symbolic `f`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and there is discussion about it [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/8242).

Comment: I would say the case described in your link differs from the one here. In the link the problem is cases like the numerical evaluation of `1/0`, whereas here no such numerical problems arise. I assume the problem is that the OP wants `evalf` to return something mixed with numerical `2` and symbolic `f`.

Comment: referenced on the page I site is a list of related issues, e.g. https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/6974 is similar to the case given here.